# Deployments of formula fields and validation rule and workflow rule

Tags: deployment

While deploying from sandbox to production org. Is formula field .Validation rule ,workflow rules associated field values like formulas ,rules are also deployed??

If the values associated with formula fields, validation rule are not deployed then we have to explicitly mentioned in prod org ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're deploying whole object something like this:

   `<types>
       <members>Custom__c</members>
       <name>CustomObject</name>
   </types>`

then you don't need to deploy all it's validation rules explicitly. It's included in Object's definition.

2. **Workflow** rules needs to be deployed explicitly.
3. However if you're moving some **customFields** of a particular object then you need to move validation rules as well. **Formula** fields are also custom Fields so any formula written will be deployed along with it. In this case your package.xml should be like this:

   `<types>
       <members>Custom__c.Assign_To_is_Mandatory</members>
       <name>ValidationRule</name>
   </types>
   <types>
       <members>Custom__c.IS_REAP_Record__c</members>
       <name>CustomField</name>
   </types>`